# New hash key has null value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

The following works as expected:

```
require 'json'

hash = {}
hash['some_key'] = false
hash['another_key'] = "that"
hash['my_key'] = hash.delete('some_key')
puts hash.to_json
```

Result

```
{"another_key":"that","my_key":false}
```

However, when I try the following, it results in a null value for the new key. Also, the old key doesn't get deleted:

```
require 'whois-parser'
require 'json'

c = Whois::Client.new
record = c.lookup('google.com')
parser = record.parser

msg = {}
for prop in Whois::Parser::PROPERTIES
  msg[prop] = parser.send(prop)
end

msg['available'] = msg.delete('available?')
puts msg.to_json
```

Result:

```
{
  "disclaimer":"TERMS OF USE: ...",
  "domain":"google.com",
  "domain_id":"2138514_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN",
  "status":"registered",
  "available?":false,
  "registered?":true,
  "created_on":"1997-09-15 00:00:00 -0700",
  "updated_on":"2018-02-21 10:45:07 -0800",
  "expires_on":"2020-09-13 21:00:00 -0700",
  "registrar":"#<struct Whois::Parser::Registrar id=\"292\", name=\"MarkMonitor, Inc.\", organization=\"MarkMonitor, Inc.\", url=\"http://www.markmonitor.com\">",
  "registrant_contacts":[],
  "admin_contacts":[],
  "technical_contacts":[],
  "nameservers":["ns2.google.com","ns1.google.com","ns4.google.com","ns3.google.com"],
  "available":null
}
```

Why is the key `available?` still set and why has the key `available` the value `null`?

Comment: your example doesn't show the `available?` key being set. How are we to know it is in fact NOT NULL?

Comment: Maybe your keys are symbols? Try to access it as `msg.delete(:available?)`. And change `puts msg.to_json` to `puts msg`, to see real keys format

Comment: @Vasilisa you are absolutely right, this should be the answer. According to the docs properties returns a hash with symbols as keys: https://whoisrb.org/docs/v3/parser/#properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mbuechmann said, `Whois::Parser::PROPERTIES` is an array of symbols. It means that your `msg` hash has symbolic keys, and you can't access them as strings.

```
msg = {}

# it is more common way for iteration in ruby
Whois::Parser::PROPERTIES.each do |prop| 
  msg[prop] = parser.send(prop)
end

msg[:available] = msg.delete(:available?)

# don't convert msg to json to check real keys format
puts msg
```